# How to convert Matlab code to jar

Tags: jar, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have a Matlab code which I need to convert it to jar file.

I need the required tools for it and steps to convert matlab code to Jar.

I have searched in Google regarding this and couldn't get any steps for this. Can some list the steps in detail and the required tools? Screenshots in answers would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically use the add-on product [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/). If you take a look at that page, there a number of written and video tutorials that will walk you through how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the link I will go through and get back to you.

Comment: It would be good if I get few steps rather than searching the entire link?

Comment: It would be good if you did your own work. The tutorial material there is already summarized and easy to follow.

Comment: Sorry sir. I didnt ask you to do my work. I just asked if there is any quick steps which you are familiar with. Trying to be sarcastic doesn't make any sense!! Asking question doesn't mean I am not doing my work and answering me doesnt mean you are working for me, I know you are replying out of your interest. But trying to be rude or sarcastic never helps any one.

Comment: No sarcasm or rudeness was intended at all. Your work appears to involve learning how to make a jar file from MATLAB code, and it would be best if you did that yourself, rather than me trying to squeeze a complex process into 'quick steps'. Like I said, the material on the link is already summarized and easy to follow, and I am not able to condense it any more for you. Just read through it, or watch the videos.